# Cortex M4 invalid frame address during Hardfault

Tags: embedded, freertos, cortex-m

I'm trying to debug a Hardfault I'm getting at my Cortex-m4 MCU (ATSAM4E16). I've been reading https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/cortex-m-hardfault-debug and https://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html?_ga=2.253492809.1735547670.1679491095-94909923.1670502073 in order to see what's going on in the MCU. I ended up with the following

```
#define HARDFAULT_HANDLING_ASM(_x)               \
  __asm volatile(                                \
      "tst lr, #4 \n"                            \
      "ite eq \n"                                \
      "mrseq r0, msp \n"                         \
      "mrsne r0, psp \n"                         \
      "b my_fault_handler_c \n"                  \
                                                 )


#define HALT_IF_DEBUGGING()                              \
  do {                                                   \
    if ((*(volatile uint32_t *)0xE000EDF0) & (1 << 0)) { \
      __asm("bkpt 1");                                   \
    }                                                    \
} while (0)


typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) ContextStateFrame {
  uint32_t r0;
  uint32_t r1;
  uint32_t r2;
  uint32_t r3;
  uint32_t r12;
  uint32_t lr;
  uint32_t return_address;
  uint32_t xpsr;
} sContextStateFrame;

// Disable optimizations for this function so "frame" argument
// does not get optimized away
__attribute__((optimize("O0")))
void my_fault_handler_c(sContextStateFrame *frame) {
  // If and only if a debugger is attached, execute a breakpoint
  // instruction so we can take a look at what triggered the fault
  HALT_IF_DEBUGGING();

  // Logic for dealing with the exception. Typically:
  //  - log the fault which occurred for postmortem analysis
  //  - If the fault is recoverable,
  //    - clear errors and return back to Thread Mode
  //  - else
  //    - reboot system
}
/**
 * \brief Default interrupt handler for unused IRQs.
 */
void Dummy_Handler(void)
{
    HARDFAULT_HANDLING_ASM();
}
```

which I added to the exceptions.c in ASF/cmsis/sam4e.

The problem is that when I'm trying to print the "my_fault_handler_c:frame" in gdb the address is invalid. The address is frame=0x1ffffe60 which does not seem to be unaligned? I do not hit vApplicationStackOverflowHook nor vApplicationMallocFailedHook before the handler kicks in.

All the handlers is using the "Dummy_Handler", but from what I can see the WDT_Handler kicks in first then if I override that fuction the UsageFault_Handler kicks in. If override UsageFault the HardFault_Handler jumps in.

I'm using the latest FreeRTOS (202212-01).

I've tried the "other" solution recommended from FreeRTOS (the FreeRTOS link) but that does not seem to help me neither.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, the normal way to debug such things on a MCU with on-chip instruction trace is to place a breakpoint inside the hard fault handler (default one or custom don't matter), then view the trace to instantly find what caused it. All you need is a half-decent debugger that can display C code out of the contents of the trace.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your sp is not pointing to the context state but to some other values that are pushed into the stack after interrupt call by the compiled exception handler.

Try to declare declare your interrupt handler as `__attribute__((naked))` so your compiler doesn't push things on the stack by himself. Probably that's what is happening. You should handle also the exception return by yourself.

P.s. post the disassembly for your interrupt handler for more insights!